# If $u \in H_0^1(\Omega) \cap L^p(\Omega)$ and $\Delta u \in L^p(\Omega)$ then $u \in W^{2, p}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

How to show the following?

> If $u \in H_0^1(\Omega) \cap L^p(\Omega)$,  $\Delta u \in L^p(\Omega)$ then $u \in W^{2, p}(\Omega)$.

This is part of the Brezis-Kato regularity argument as presented by Struwe in *Variational Methods*, Appendix B, but I am unable to prove it.

Any hints will be the most appreciated.

Comment: That's elliptic regularity. Can be found in Gilbarg-Trudingar chapter 8,9

Comment: I could only find results regarding $p = 2$ (Theorem 8.8 in the said book). But what if we use the uniqueness of the solution of $-\Delta u = f$ (Theorem 8.3) and that the Newtonian potential is a solution, together with Theorem 9.9?

Comment: It seems that you can use 9.15 (say for $p\le 2$ your $u$ is in $W^{1,p}_0$).

Comment: Indeed, it solves my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ArcticChar A friend raised a question: we need to have it for $p > 2$ as well. I believe my first argument was better. Opinions?

Comment: This is just the Agmon-Douglis-Nirenberg Theorem